# is there any way to change still images to video in php on windows plate form

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a scenario for creating a video files using different images.

What can I do is, basically I have images and I want create a video file using PHP.

Can any one please suggest the start up point for this? Have done image capture from video and converting the video using Ffmpeg so I have think of Ffmpeg but, I think it will not allow to create a video.

i need to develop a movie with more then 5 pic. If i added images , then php convert it to movies or video. is there any toll to convert images to video in php on windows??? 
thanks

Comment: i recheck my question and edit it, that may be helpful for me and other members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, in pure PHP... **No...**

Long answer:
If you're able to use external tools  (ffmpeg e.g.) than you could use PHP to run a commandline command to start ffmpeg...

Look at the following php.net pages:

[exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

[passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

[shell-exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: thanks for answering. i think i have to move on ffmpeg. is there any tutorial about this tool (ffmpeg). I didn't find accurate tutorial about this tool

Comment: I did the googling for you ;)

[superuser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/343955/converting-images-to-video-using-ffmpeg-on-windows)